# What is "the hole of a pet bottle on the top" called?

Tags: word-request

It's very subtle but I cannot come up with a simple word to indicate the hole on a pet bottle's top, where the liquid comes out when the bottle is leaned.

I guess it's a very simple word that I couldn't find an article or an informative image that describes how each part of a pet bottle is called. Is it just called a **hole**?

Comment: I think I found one. It's called 'spout' I guess.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean a bottle for a small animal (a pet), or a bottle made out of PET (a kind of plastic)? Why is it different from a glass bottle?

Answer (score 1):

The opening of a bottle is normally called its 'mouth'. If you're talking about a bottle that a rat or hamster drinks out of, it might have a pipe attached to its mouth so that the water can drip out slowly as the animal drinks. That pipe would be called a spout, and it's the only case I can think of where a bottle would have a 'spout'.

A spout is usually a depression on the edge of a container that directs liquid to flow out of the container in one place. A pitcher might have a spout that helps you pour its contents into a glass without spilling them. Buildings might have water spouts around the edges of their roofs to channel the water off. It can also be a tube sticking out of a vessel designed for pouring the liquid from the vessel. The example that comes to mind is a tea kettle. It has a handle on one side and a spout for pouring on the other. There's even a children's song about the handle and spout of a tea kettle. We don't usually use 'spout' for the opening of a bottle.

Comment: A wine bottle can have a metal tube attached to its mouth  to help avoid drips that may cause stains. The whole attachment is called a pourer,  but the tube is a spout. A bottle that has a valved opening, to let liquid floew or be halted at will, has a spout. Still excellent answer. See (https://www.google.com/search?q=wine+pourer&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=fir=AU8o3y_1ThFJdM%253A%252CjlPoWGZgvHC9GM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRKBdDAolz-BOZfYCAtH1bUDOXE0A&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi29YfLz7DjAhXTF80KHZddAVAQ9QEwA3oECAUQBA#imgrc=AU8o3y_1ThFJdM:)